# How to find the matching string within the string using regex and javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

I was trying to match the pattern within the string and get a part of the matched substrings.

What am I trying to do?

Consider the string

```
I am <user-name id="3" text="myname lname"/> <user-name id="32" text="name1 name2"/>
```

I want to match the strings

`<user-name id="3" text="myname lname"/>` and
`<user-name id="32" text="name1 name2"/>`

and get the value of the text attributes.

So from above matched substrings I want the values "myname lname" and "name1 name2"

I want to extract these values from the original string and create the string like below,

```
"I am myname lname name1 name2"
```

Also the values from text attribute should be in bold

so the final string should like below,

```
I am <strong>myname lname</strong> <strong>name1 name2</strong>
```

What I have tried to do?

Since I am new to using regex expressions, I have tried to do step by step.

So I started to first match the pattern like below

```
let str1 = str.match(/\<(user-name\sid="\d+"\stext=[\w\s]+)\/>/g);
```

but this gives me null. I am not sure how to get the final output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to parse HTML or tags using regex. Here is a better method in my opinion - assuming the text starts with text and the rest are user-name tags

```js
const str = `I am <user-name id="3" text="myname lname"/> <user-name id="32" text="name1 name2"/>`

let domFragment = document.createElement("div");

domFragment.innerHTML=str;

let text = [domFragment.firstChild.wholeText];

[...domFragment.querySelectorAll("user-name")].forEach(
  ele => text.push(`<strong>${ele.getAttribute("text")}</strong>`)
);
console.log(text.join(" "));
```

Comment: thanks. i want this text embedded in strong tag to be bold but instead i have it rendered as a string. could you please let me know how to fix it.

Comment: Just insert it in a container using innerHTML

Comment: i have used the text variable inside div element like this.<div className="text">{text}</div>

Comment: using reactjs. text should return a jsx.

Comment: <div className="text" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: text}} /> used this and i get the output like below  I am ,myname lname,name1 name2

Comment: works for me now. i modified this ele => text.push(<span>{" " +`${ele.getAttribute("text")}`}</span>) and used the variable text within div tag

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a gentle warning... while you can get away with it sometimes, it's generally a bad idea to parse HTML with regexes. (There are some very amusing posts on that topic.)

As for your regex, the first thing I notice is that you're missing the quotes you need to match for the `text` attribute value. I'll update this answer after I check more...

Here, just a little different from what you originally posted:

`let matches = str.match(/\<user-name\sid="(\d+)"\s+text="([\w\s]+)"\/>/)`

I just added the missing quotes, made it a little more flexible about whitespace, and parenthetically grouped the two pieces you'll want to extract from the string, and took out the outer set of parentheses. Oh, and I took the `g` flag out too — not needed.

`matches[1]` will be the `id` attribute value, `matches[2]` will be the value for `text`.

`matches[2].split(' ')` will further break down that `text` value for you.

Comment: No, the missing quotes I mentioned solved the problem, it was the answer. My update just polished things up with some improvements.

Comment: after retreiving the matched patterns how can i get the string after "text=" .i can do it for single match found using substring method. but if there is more than one match found i have to map through each match and extract string after "text=" and append that to original string with this extracted strings within strong tag how to do it? thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer some more, which hopefully answers your questions. Please note that I took out the outer parens that were there before too this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string as HTML and use DOM manipulation to get the values, here is an example:

```js
const content = 'I am <user-name id="3" text="myname lname"/> <user-name id="32" text="name1 name2"/>';
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(content, 'text/html');

const getTextAttrVal = (n) => {
  if (n.matches && n.matches('user-name')) {
    return `<strong>${n.getAttribute('text')}</strong>`;
  }
  return '';
}

const recursion = (n) => {
  if (n && n.childNodes && n.childNodes.length) {
    return getTextAttrVal(n) + [...n.childNodes].map(recursion).join('');
  }
  return getTextAttrVal(n) || n.textContent;
}

const result = [...doc.body.childNodes].map(recursion).join(' ');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @mplungjan I will edit my answer to add the missing parts.

Comment: thanks. i get this string from an object like so obj = { property1: "i am <user-name id="3" text="myname lname"/> <user-name id="32" text="name1 name2"/>',}